# how do I override upper-bounds in a haskell project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like to use kind equality, which seems only present in GHC head for now.

I made a system-install of GHC, and in my project I added a `snapshot.yaml`

```
resolver: nightly-2016-12-31
compiler: ghc-8.1.20170103
```

and updated `stack.yaml` accordingly

```
resolver:
  name: snapshot
  location: snapshot.yaml
```

I can see using `stack path` that it picks the correct compiler.

When I build my project I now have

```
In the dependencies for array-0.5.1.1:
    base-4.10.0.0 must match >=4.5 && <4.10 (latest applicable is 4.9.0.0)
needed due to bookkeeper-0.2.4 -> array-0.5.1.1
```

How can I override from my project the upper-bound declared by array-0.5.1.1, which is probably not *actually* required ?

Comment: Try `--allow-newer`.

Comment: Oh, apparently that's not a CLI option. [You can set it in the stack.yaml though.](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#allow-newer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that the `nightly-2016-12-31` snapshot [uses GHC 8.0.1 and *base* 4.9.0.0](https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2016-12-31), and so it is incompatible with your installation of GHC 8.1. It should be enough to [set the resolver to `ghc-8.1.20170103`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#other-resolver-values), so that no snapshots are used. (There is also a [`system-ghc`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#system-ghc) option; however, given that Stack is already using the correct compiler I guess it won't be necessary to turn that on.) If you need packages not bundled with GHC, you will have to add them to the `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml` (if you already have a .cabal file specifying your dependencies, `stack solver --update-config` can be used to fill that in automatically).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. if I set the resolver to ghc-8.1.20170103, a solver attempt finds no plans as it complains about all the libraries which specify this upper bound on base. so frustrating.

Comment: oh ok, the solver ignores the 'allow-newer' flag set in stack.yaml. just attempting to build and add as required packages what comes out leads to some compilation.